# cmd + period(.) does not work as expected

Tags: cocoa, macos, keyboard, shortcut

I develop an application on Mac using **cocoa**. I need to handle **cmd + period(.)** keyboard event as a command I designed. But now the cmd + period(.) keyboard event does not well handled as I expected.

In the cocoa keyEvent handle process, if the application object processes a key event and it turns out not to be a key equivalent or a key interface control event, it then sends it to the key window in a sendEvent: message. The window object invokes the keyDown: method in the first responder. My handle for cmd + period(.)  is in **keyDown: method**.

But the problem is that Mac treates cmd + period(.) key the same as Escape key. The key window first searches the view hierarchy for a view whose key equivalent is Escape or Command-., whichever was entered. But none of these views handles the key equivalent, then a **cancel: action message** is sent to the first responder in the responder chain. 
**So cmd + period(.) is handled as a cancel operation before it reaches keyDown: method.**

Can anyone have some idea to solve this problem. And make the cmd + period(.) be handled as I expected but as cancel command. Thank you.

What is more, it is better not handle the cmd + period(.) when do the key equivalent check(**performkeyEquivalent**).

Comment: In the interest of consistency between apps you should probably not use Command + period(.) - users expect it to mean "stop" or "cancel".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the default handling, you need to catch the keyboard event earlier in the chain. For example, subclass NSWindow and override -sendEvent, or even more thorough, subclass NSApplication and override -nextEventMatchingMask (all events will pass through this function).